# React hooks Cannot read properties of undefined using react

Tags: reactjs, yup

Im getting this error, I have read the similar questions before posting with no real help on why mine is not working, it works in code sandbox but when i bring it into vscode it throws this error and renders nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated .

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

```
const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().min(6).max(32).required(),
});

function Fields() {
  const {register , handleSubmit, errors} = useForm({
    validationSchema: SignupSchema
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ref={register} />
      {errors.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}




</form>
  </div>
)
  
}
```

Comment: from what we have been provided I assume `errors` at some point in time is `undefined` maybe try `{errors?.name && <p>{errors.name.message}</p>}`

Comment: good idea. now im getting Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function, gonna work that now.